# stdlib rename api opening new handle when trying to write over network to mounted location

Tags: file, exception, smb, filehandle, mount-point

I have a folder present in windows , which i am mounting from mac side using smb.
Into this mounted location i'm trying to write a new file over the network.
After writing the data into the file , the handle is closed.

Now i need to rename the file over network from mac side .
So for that, making use of stdlib rename(), observed that the file rename is working fine
but renaming of the file is opening a new handle which cannot be captured.

When i try to delete
the same file over network using DeleteFile api ,the file gets marked for delete , but actually
fails to delete and the permission of the files gets changed as the the file is still open(which i came
to know from computer management open files).

So stdlib rename api is opening the new handle while
renaming which prevents the file from delete. stuck with this issue and Need inputs to fix it.
Using Xcode version 7.3.1 for development.